# On Android studio the format specifiers %s are visible in my edit text and I don't know how to remove them

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext

```
`<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <!-- App name -->
    <string name="app_name">Form</string>
    <!--Email subject -->
    <string name="vehicle_finance_application_for">Vehicle finance application for :<xliff:g example="Amy" id="surname">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <!-- Form header  -->
    <string name="vehicle_finance_application">Vehicle finance application</string>
    <!--Mxo cars application form order    -->
    <!-- Personal information-->
    <string name="surname">Surname :<xliff:g example="Peterson" id="surname">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="name">Full names :<xliff:g example="John" id="name">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="id_number">Id number :<xliff:g example="560708080" id="id number">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <string name="cell_number">Cell number :<xliff:g example="0123513460" id="cell number">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <string name="email">Email :<xliff:g example="kevin@gmail.com" id="email">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="land_line">landline :<xliff:g example="0127395679" id="landline">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string-array name="marital_status_array">
        <item>Not Selected</item>
        <item>Yes I am married</item>
        <item>No I am not married</item>
        <item>Divorced</item>
        <item>Widowed</item>
        </string-array>
    <string-array name="graduate_status_array">
        <item>Not Selected</item>
        <item>Yes I am graduate</item>
        <item>No I am not a graduate</item>
    </string-array>
    <string name="home_address">Home address : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="postal_code">Postal code : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <string name="how_many_years_have_you_been_living_there">How many years have you been living there :<xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <string name="postal_address">Postal address :<xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string-array name="homeowner_status_array">
        <item>Not Selected</item>
        <item>Yes I am a home owner</item>
        <item>No I don\'t own property</item>
    </string-array>
    <!--Employment information-->
    <string name="employers_name">Employers name : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="employers_contact">Employers contact number : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="employers_address">Employers address : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="number_of_years_employed">Number of years employed : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <string name="occupation">Occupation : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="industry">Industry : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <!--Bank details-->
    <string name="bank">Bank : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="bank_account_number">Bank account number : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <string name="bank_branch">Bank branch code : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <!--Spouse Information-->
    <string name="spouse_name">Spouse name : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <string name="spouse_surname">Spouse surname : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <string name="spouse_id_number">Spouse id number : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="spouse_contact_number">Spouse contact number : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <!--Relative not residing with you-->
    <string name="relationship_of_relative">What is the relationship : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <string name="full_names_of_relative">Full names of relative : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <string name="surname_of_relative">Surname of relative : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="phone_number_of_relative">Phone number of relative : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <string name="address_of_relative">Address of relative : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <!--Financial information-->
    <string name="gross">Gross : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="net_income">Net income : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="do_you_have_additional_income">Do you have additional income : <xliff:g example="0127395679" id="landline">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="source_of_additional_income">Source of additional income : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="clothing_account">Clothing account : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <!--Expenses-->
    <string name="personal_loan">Personal loan : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <string name="insurance">Insurance : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <string name="bond_or_renting">Bond or renting payment : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <string name="municipality">Municipality : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <string name="credit_card">Credit card : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="overdraft">Overdraft : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <string name="phone_account">Phone account : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="transport">Transport cost : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="food_or_entertainment">Food or entertainment : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <string name="education_fees">Education fees : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <string name="maintenance">Maintenance : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <string name="household_expenses">Household expenses : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="other_expenses">Other expenses : <xliff:g example="Po box 1202 shirley street" id="address">%s</xliff:g> </string>
    <!--Send button-->
    <string name="send">Send</string>

    <!--Parameter strings for spinner questions in vehicle application form-->
    <string name="are_you_married">Married : <xliff:g example="0127395679" id="landline">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="are_you_a_graduate">Graduate : <xliff:g example="0127395679" id="landline">%s</xliff:g></string>
    <string name="are_you_a_home_owner">Home owner : <xliff:g example="0127395679" id="landline">%s</xliff:g></string>

    <!-- Spinner header text questions   -->
    <string name="please_tell_us_if_you_married">Please tell us if you married?</string>
    <string name="please_tell_us_if_you_a_graduate">Please tell us if you a graduate ?</string>
    <string name="do_you_own_property">Do you own property ?</string>
<!--Header for sections of the vehicle application     -->
    <string name="personal_information">Personal information</string>
    <string name="employer_information">Employer Information</string>
    <string name="spouse_information">Spouse information</string>
    <string name="relative_information">Relative information</string>
    <string name="how_are_you_related">How are you related</string>
    <string name="personal_expenses">Personal Expenses</string>
    <string name="financial_information">Financial information</string>
    <string name="bank_details">Bank details</string>


</resources>`
```

I'm having a problem with format specifiers being visible in the edit text. I have tried to read the Android documentation about formatting strings and I failed to understand how it all works.

I've included format character `%s` in my `string.xml` file and its does not help with format specifiers being visible in the edit text autonomously concatenating with the hint of the edit text view.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your `strings.xml` code please?

Comment: Hi ive edit out my question and provided a code snippet for the string xml. Thank you

Comment: Thank you! Now, for what do you need the specifiers?

Comment: Are they not compulsory to be included in your string.xml to identify the type of Strings you using example  %d decimal number or % s for Strings? cause if you do not include them you get an error calling the getString(R.string.surname,theSurname) method

Comment: After adding the %s to the string.xml the error goes away but another problem occurs when these specifiers get included in your hint attribute value of your edit text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not hide it from user. You can set empty string from your code to make it go away. Like this

```
if(surname == "" ||surname == null){
yourEditText.setText(getString(R.string.surname,""))
}
```